# Moving Win7 C:\ to another partition on same hdd

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I would like to know about moving Win7:C\ to another partition on same hdd as it has 25GB (which moving from XP I thought was adequate). Is there a way that Win7 or some free tool allows to do it?

Thanks in advance,
-S

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, you can howover resize the partition.

Right click Computer, choose Manage.

Under Disk Management, right click the C: partition an click Extend Volume.

Just make sure the disk has unpartitioned space and you should be able to extend your C: volume to a new size of your choice.

Comment: The layout is such that the 50GB partition where I would like to move to is before the current 25GB. I have Linux parititions that can't be fiddled with coming right after the 25GB (C:). Can this layout be handled safely?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you certainly will have to do that from another boot. There is probably no way you can move the system's partition while its running in it.